# Location of The Divine forest - Naimisaranya

Tags: vishnu, krishna, bhagavata-purana

> नैमिषेऽनिमिषक्षेत्रे ऋषय: शौनकादय: ।
> सत्रं स्वर्गायलोकाय सहस्रसममासत ॥ ४ ॥

Meaning -

> Once, in a holy place in the forest of Naimiṣāraṇya, great sages headed by the sage Śaunaka assembled to perform a great thousand-year sacrifice for the satisfaction of the Lord and His devotees.

Where is the forest of Naimisaranya located? Is there any mention of the forest in any other puranas, This sloka also mentions the forest to be Vishnu's favourite spot? What does "nimiṣa-kṣetre" mean?

Comment: According to Bannaje Govindacharya, It is forest where sage dahichi did penance and offered his spine as vajrayudha.. it is the same place where chakra of lord finally fell making a pond for dahichi to bath known as chakra theertha. even today its there. Apart from this forest provided conducive environment where sages can do penance without worry about food. Naimisa is tree where Naimisa fruit was given.. it filled their stomach.. where this forest is full of such trees naimisa.. Sage sunaka was the provided srimad bhagavatam from sage suta. He was the chancellor of university run by him.

Comment: Daily 10000 people have to be fed Naimisa fruit. without need for cooking and plantation ..

Comment: @PrasannaR That is helpful info, thx for posting these comments :)

Comment: Thank you @PrasannaR

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Where is the forest of Naimisaranya located?

> In the Adi Parva of the Mahabharata, the forest is mentioned as situated towards east (prācīm diśam) of the mountain regions of Himavat which contained many sacred spots. In the epic, there are frequent references to rṣis living in Naimiṣāraṇya and performing sacrifices extending for years.

What does "nimiṣa-kṣetre" mean?

> The Brahmanas derive the name Naimiṣāraṇya from 'nimiṣā', "a twinkling of the eye"; hence Naimiṣāraṇya means "a forest or pool where in the twinkling of an eye sage Gauramukha destroyed an army of Asuras."

Is there any mention of the forest in any other puranas?

> 1. In the Varaha Purana, it has been described as the region where Daityas (demons) were slain within a nimiśa (smallest unit of time) and the place was made a abode of peace.
> 2. It is also mentioned in the Kāthaka-Saṃhitā.
> 3. According to the Rāmāyaṇa, Naimiṣa was situated along the Gomati River. The sanctity attached to the place was such that Rāma desired to celebrate Aśvamedha sacrifice in this forest, and accordingly, placing his younger brother Lakṣmana assisted by the priests in charge of the steed, himself went to the forest. It was during the sacrifice that Valmiki with his disciples came there and constructed some comfortable huts at a distance. Then Lava and Kuśa recited the whole Ramayana which convinced Rama that they were the twin sons of Sītā. Ultimately, Mother Earth appeared at Sita's invocation and, proving her innocence, accompanied her into the bowels of the earth
> 4. Naimisaranyam, also known as Neemsar, Nimsar or Nimkhar, and the Naimishnath Devaraja temple, is a Hindu temple dedicated to Vishnu located in the north Indian state of Uttar Pradesh. It is one of the Divya Desams, the 108 temples of Vishnu revered in Nalayira Divya Prabandham by the 12 poet saints called the Alvars. The temple is believed to be of significant antiquity with contributions at different times from the ruling kings. The temple is counted as one of the eight temples of Vishnu that self-manifested and is classified as Swayamvyaktha Kshetra

Source - https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Naimisaranya, https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Naimi%E1%B9%A3%C4%81ra%E1%B9%87ya_(forest)